# Adding extended fragment to Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have been trying to build a Master-Detail f low in android but wanted to change one of the detail fragments to a different fragment. As this is one of my first Android applications, I was just trying to make a picture appear on this new fragment. For this, I built the following two classes

1) Fragment class ( displays the picture to be displayed )

```
 package com.userName.miscapp;

import com.userName.miscapp.dummy.DummyContent;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PictureFragment extends Fragment {



    // Default Copy Constructor for the fragment
    public PictureFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater , ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_simple_picture, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

2) Activity to display the same

```
package com.userName.miscapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class SimplePicture extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Create the detail fragment and add it to the activity
            // using a fragment transaction.
            Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
            arguments.putString(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID,
                    getIntent().getStringExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID));
            PictureFragment frag = new PictureFragment();
            frag.setArguments(arguments);
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.simple_picture_container,frag).commit();
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_picture);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.simple_picture, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

On compilation, it does not recognize the PictureFragment to be an extension of Fragment class. This is inspite of it being clearly written in the first file. Searching for solutions on Stackoverflow said to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity and trying to use getSupportFragmentManager() neither of which helped.

PS : Using 11 as the base for the current application.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because you are using `android.app.Fragment` from new API  in conjunction with `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` from support library, you should replace import in your PictureFragment from `android.app.Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to make it work.

Comment: Had exactly the same error, didn't notice the imports :-)